# TypeScript List won't validate the element's type when initializing with a list

Tags: typescript

The following code in TypeScript won't throw any error nor warning,
even though the 1st element is not compliant to `IFileStatus`.

```
interface IFileStatus {   a: string;   b: number; }
let statuses: IFileStatus[] = [
                {
                    a: '123',
                    c: [],
                }];
```

If alternatively, trying to push the element, it does show the expected error (`a` should be a string, `b` property is missing, and `c` does not exist and is not allowed).

```
statuses.push({
                a: 123,
                c: []
            });
```

Why the 1st code does not show the expected error?

how can I enable validation of elements type in the list in the initial declaration?

I'm using the very latest TypeScript 3.5.2

UPDATE #1+2:
At least WebStorm complaints for other errors the same as in the gulp-typescript build.

The tsconfig.json is below.

> {
>       "compilerOptions": {
>           "declaration": false,
>           "noEmitOnError": true,
>           "noUnusedLocals": true,
>
> ```
>     "noExternalResolve": true,
>
>     "target": "es5",
>     "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
>     "baseUrl": "",
>     "sourceMap": false,
>     "typeRoots": [
>         "./node_modules/@types",
>         "./typings"
>     ],
>     "types": [
>         "jasmine",
>         "node"
>     ],
>     "paths": {
>         "@ngtools/json-schema": [
>             "./packages/@ngtools/json-schema/src"
>         ],
>         "@ngtools/logger": [
>             "./packages/@ngtools/logger/src"
>         ],
>         "@ngtools/webpack": [
>             "./packages/@ngtools/webpack/src"
>         ]
>     }
> },
> "exclude": [
>     "packages/@angular/cli/blueprints/*/files/**/*",
>     "dist/**/*",
>     "node_modules/**/*",
>     "tmp/**/*"
> ] }
> ```

The tslint.json is below.

> ```
> {
>     "rules": {
>         "max-line-length": [
>             true,
>             150
>         ],
>         "no-inferrable-types": true,
>         "class-name": true,
>         "comment-format": [
>             true
>         ],
>         "indent": [
>             true,
>             "spaces"
>         ],
>         "eofline": true,
>         "no-duplicate-variable": true,
>         "no-eval": true,
>         "no-arg": true,
>         "no-internal-module": true,
>         "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
>         "no-bitwise": true,
>         "no-unused-expression": true,
>         "no-var-keyword": true,
>         "no-consecutive-blank-lines": [true, 1],
>         "triple-equals": true,
>         "one-line": [
>             true,
>             "check-catch",
>             "check-else",
>             "check-open-brace",
>             "check-whitespace"
>         ],
>         "quotemark": [
>             true,
>             "single",
>             "avoid-escape"
>         ],
>         "semicolon": [
>             true,
>             "always"
>         ],
>         "typedef-whitespace": [
>             true,
>             {
>                 "call-signature": "nospace",
>                 "index-signature": "nospace",
>                 "parameter": "nospace",
>                 "property-declaration": "nospace",
>                 "variable-declaration": "nospace"
>             }
>         ],
>         "curly": true,
>         "variable-name": [
>             true,
>             "ban-keywords",
>             "check-format",
>             "allow-leading-underscore",
>             "allow-pascal-case"
>         ],
>         "whitespace": [
>             true,
>             "check-branch",
>             "check-decl",
>             "check-operator",
>             "check-separator",
>             "check-type"
>         ]
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgBsIGUxxgCuAzsgN7JwBcyJYUoA5gNzIBGtIRAtu9GwC+AKBxg6BYiQglaGbHkmkA2gF1kAXmTLyw5Pqq0A5AEYATAGYjAGj0GEtNbcGrhw+oVIyAdAAdSABYAFLoGhsjmFrZhDtqqzgCUbh5SPv4kwaEGNMimljZ2+rFOwoJJ7krSJH6BIYXheVaJQA). Please provide any compiler options you have enabled/disabled.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall thanks a lot you are right, I started with the assumption my gulp workflow had correct TSLint settings. I have the tslint.json but seems to be ignored, need to check why.

Comment: TSLint doesn’t matter since this isn’t a linting error, it’s a compiler error. You may wish to try enabling TypeScript’s strict mode, but the playgound seems to indicate that strict isn’t needed to produce this error. Is the code you’ve posted *exactly* what you have?

Comment: Thanks alot. Again for the good question. Not exactly the same. I using another interface. In my own example here, mmm, bit embarassed, it does show the error, but I found the problem in my code, see the answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason: an 'any' element was added in between, and for whatever reason, TypeScript assumed the whole list was any[]. And so the developer was free to do whatever with the elements of the list.

[Demo of bypassing the TypeScript type check of a list during direct value initialization](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDFgBsIGUxxgCuAzsgN7JwBcyJYUoA5gNzIBGtIRAtu9GwC+AKGEB6McgBCATQAKAQVy4AogBFkCABYQEAa2E4wdAsRIQSAJloZseU6QDaAXWQBeZI-LDkvqrUsAZgAaHz9OZAByEi0AeyIsABMOFDhkbj5oSNC-TVoXHL9gAGE4EDVYhRAATzAtZlpI6otI4UFQyMiqMjLq51F6QlILSwA6AAdSLQAKb1yaZABGIMLfBHznUPbhTu6qGoBKAYdzKwmp2bDfBcjlwOyrvM9Nto6uuB7D46HTscmYy7zRp3B7bXYffbVA5AA)